# New line in table containing some (but not all) information from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to enter a line in a table which collects information from several other tables as well as external parameters. The stored procedure is supposed to look about like this, although much longer:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp1;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1(IN para1 INT, IN para2 INT,IN para3 INT)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO table100 VALUES(
NULL, #AaS_id, Auto_Increment
DEFAULT, #AaS_ts, Def
SELECT info1 FROM table2 WHERE id1 = para1,
SELECT info2 FROM table3 WHERE id2 = para2, 
para3);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

SQL does not like "SELECT". Any help, as this approach does not work? Thx, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store the results of the two subqueries into variables, and then insert them:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp1;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 (IN para1 INT, IN para2 INT,IN para3 INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE i1 VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE i2 VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT info1 INTO i1 FROM table2 WHERE id1 = para1
    SELECT info2 INTO i2 FROM table3 WHERE id2 = para2

    INSERT INTO table100
    VALUES (NULL, DEFAULT, i1, i2, para3);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```